# how to draw a bitmap from drawable by pressing an actionbar button?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-drawable

I have the code for the onOptionsItemSelected as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_draw:
        draw();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        openSettings();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

What should I write for draw() in order to place the following image from

`android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_draw"`

in a specific coordinate in canvas? like:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 250, 500, null);
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Guys anyone can help me with this???

Comment: I am new to this. So far I manage to draw a bitmap where ever you touch but now I would like to draw the same bitmap in a specific coordinates by pressing a button in the action bar.  I really appreciate if you can help me.